# web scraping using python beautifulsoup getting values after equal sign

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWYl6.png)

Using Python, I need to get the name of the colors.

For example, data-label="BLACK" - here I need to get BLACK as the output

So far, I have:

```
Color=section.find("div",{"class":"sfa-pa-product-swatches-thumbnails-container"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the "thumbnail" elements and get the value of the `data-label` attribute:

```
colors = [elm.get("data-label", "No color specified") 
          for elm in soup.find_all("div", class_="sfa-pa-product-swatches-color")]
```

The complete code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.saksfifthavenue.com/Handbags/shop/_/N-52jzot/Ne-6lvnb5?FOLDER%3C%3Efolder_id=2534374306622829"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

for product in soup.select("#product-container [id^=product-]"):
    product_name = product.find(class_="product-designer-name").get_text()
    colors = [elm["data-label"]
              for elm in product.find_all("div", class_="sfa-pa-product-swatches-color")]
    print(product_name, colors)
```

Prints:

```
(u'Bao Bao Issey Miyake', [u'SILVER'])
(u'Nancy Gonzalez', [u'BLACK', u'BLUSH'])
(u'Bao Bao Issey Miyake', [u'GUNMETAL'])
...
(u'Saint Laurent', [u'WINE'])
(u'Fendi', [u'BLUE', u'FUCHSIA', u'WATER GREEN'])
(u'Prada', [u'LAGO'])
```

And make sure you are not violating the website's [Terms of Use](http://www.saksfifthavenue.com/html/popups/terms_of_use.jsp?bmUID=kCB2usA#sec-webuse) - stay on the legal side.

Comment: I tried this, and it gave me a KeyError: 'data-label'

Comment: @Seung okay, what do you get now (updated the code)?

Comment: I just got blanks like this - []

Comment: @Seung I don't get it - how could you got `KeyError` with the first version and a blank list with the second? it just does not make sense. Anyway, can you share the URL to the page you are parsing? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.saksfifthavenue.com/Handbags/shop/_/N-52jzot/Ne-6lvnb5?FOLDER%3C%3Efolder_id=2534374306622829

Comment: I'm trying to get the colors of the bags as the output

Comment: @Seung updated with the complete working code. Hope that helps.

Comment: for elm in product.find_all("div", class_="sfa-pa-product-swatches-color")] - here, I don't see "sfa-pa-product-swatches-color" on the page's html. Could you tell me where you got that? Thanks!

Comment: @Seung I've inspected the response returned by requests, saved it in an html file, prettified with pycharm and looked for the desired sizes. Also used the browser developer tools to recheck myself. Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you also explain this line- for product in bsObj.select("#product-container [id^=product-]"):? How did you get this- ("#product-container [id^=product-]" ?

Comment: @Seung sure, the expression inside the `select()` call is a CSS selector. It would match all elements with id starting with `product-` under the element with `id="product-container"`.

Comment: Could you share with me how to do process of saving in an html file and prettifying it? Thank you

Comment: @Seung I've just printed the `response.text` on the console and copy-pasted it into an html file, then used the PyCharm's "reformat code" feature - sort of a manual quick-and-dirty way :)